# Geometric series, $e$ and approximating with series

Tags: calculus

Im looking to understand how they are finding e to a set given of decimal points.

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n!}$$

$$s_n=1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$$

[image]

Now this is how they do it. But I am not able to see the formula of the series s. And I do not understand the way they have factored out the $\frac{1}{n!}$, as well as why it becomes (n+1)(n+2)(n+3) etc. in the denominator.

Comment: $(n+i)!=(n+i)(n+i-1)\dots(n+1)(n)(n-1)\dots1=(n+i)\dots(n+1)n!$ for $i\in\mathbb{N}^\star$. An easy way to understand is to go the other way round: expand the product and you'll find the sum.

Comment: @ALEXANDER : From you comments I'm wondering how much you know about factorials.  Do you know that $6!=\text{six factorial}=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\ {}$?

Comment: Yes I do know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$s_n$ is the partial sum of the series while $s$ is the complete sum of the series, i.e.

$$s=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n!} =1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\cdots$$

so (making a slight adjustment to the index for clarity)$$s-s_n=\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{m!} -\sum _{m=0}^{n-1 } \frac{1}{m!} =\sum _{m=n}^{\infty } \frac{1}{m!} =\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\cdots$$

and since $n!=n! \times 1$, and $(n+1)!=n! \times (n+1)$, and $(n+2)!=n! \times (n+1)(n+2)$, etc.:

$$s-s_n=\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\cdots = \frac{1}{n!}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\cdots\right).$$

Comment: Can you continue and show how they simplified to the end result

Comment: since $n+2 \gt n+1$ they say $\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} \lt \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)}=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ and similarly with the other terms, so the series sum of $s-s_n$ is bounded above by the geometric series sum.

Comment: But where I get stuck now is here: $\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) n!}$, specifically what is inside the (). I just do not get how they get this term.

Comment: Would you be able to add that to your answer?

Comment: If $|k|\lt 1$ then you have the geometric series $a+ak+ak^2+\cdots = \frac{a}{1-k}$.  Here $a=\frac1{n!}$ and $k=\frac{1}{n+1}$